# Marklogic nodejs Api error

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I have the following marklogic rest-api url :

http://marklogicserver:8060/v1/search?format=json&options=optionname&q=question

This url send me results and format them according the optionname. Everything is ok.

Now I need to do the same work with Nodejs API :

I use a querybuilder to do the same thing but my results are never formatted according to optionname.

```
qb.optionsName = 'optionname';
//qb.search = {q: question};
db.documents.query(
    qb.where(qb.parsedFrom(‘question’))
    ).result( function(results) {
        results.forEach(function(document) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(document,null,2));
        return document;
    });
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Although I am sure that the optioname is the right one, the system returns the following error message:

```
[Error: query documents: response with invalid 400 status]
message: 'query documents: response with invalid 400 status',
statusCode: 400,
body:
 { errorResponse:
    { statusCode: 400,
      status: 'Bad Request',
      messageCode: 'REST-INVALIDPARAM',
      message: 'REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: No configured options: optionname' } }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the querybuilder to the function but a *query* built by it. Try creating the query and then attaching the optionsName property like this:

```
var query = qb.where(qb.parsedFrom(‘question’))
query.optionsName = 'optionname';
db.documents
    .query(query)
    .result( function(results) {
        results.forEach(function(document) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(document,null,2));
            return document;
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The QueryBuilder defines the query entirely in the client. This approach gives the application complete flexibility for dynamic construction of queries and avoids the housekeeping of maintaining persisted query options.

To use query options persisted on the server, you can instead define a combined query as a JavaScript object and identify the persisted query options in that object:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/documents.html#toc14

However, the QueryBuilder alternative is recommended.

Hoping that clarifies,

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The problem is that I got no idea how to declare and use CombinedQueryDefinition.

Comment: var query = qb.where();
 query.optionsName = 'digital-assets';
 query.categories = ['none'];
 query.search = {
         'options':{
             'search-option':['unfiltered']
         },
     'qtext': 'aberlour'
 };

 db.documents
     .query(query)
     .result( function(results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results,null,2));
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     });

}

Answer (score 0):

Someone from marklogic gave me the good syntax:

my query.search was malformed, if it can help somebody.

```
var query = qb.where();
    query.optionsName = 'optionsname';
    query.categories = ['none'];
    query.search = {
            'options':{
                'search-option':['unfiltered']
            },
        'qtext': 'q'
    };

    db.documents
        .query(query)
        .result( function(results) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(results,null,2));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Good that you're having success, but one clarification:  you shouldn't use query builder or start with qb.where() if you're taking this approach.

Your will work just as well if your first list is:

    var query = {};